# Can't add Google Play Services to Xamarin Android Project

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, google-play-services

I have been trying to add Xamarin Google Play Services Binding to my project so that I can add admob ads to my app.

I went and installed the Nuget package, "Xamarin Google Play Services Binding"

But then when I try to run (even if I make no other changes) I get 100+ errors about packages not existing:

For example:

```
Error   31   package android.support.v4.app does not exist
    private native void n_onTabReselected (android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab p0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction p1);
```

and:

```
Error   77   package com.google.ads.mediation does not exist
private native void n_onReceivedAd (com.google.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialAdapter p0);
```

When I then go to the file I find at the top the package name is the one that claims doesn't exist, but with 'mono' attached to the front. So for example on this last error it claims that package "com.google.ads.mediation" does not exist, at the top the package itself says "package mono.com.google.ads.mediation;"

I am very new to using Xamarin and I am pulling my hair out trying to get this fixed so I would desperately appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing Google Play Services as a components instead of a Nuget Reference

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/components_walkthrough/

Comment: Thanks for your input though I tried that, same issue.

Comment: installing as components the same like nuget , as components nuget + some documentation (may be sample code , some explanation .. etc  ) but both the same